# hotkey/button to compile as necessary but NOT run (F5, and Ctrl+Shift+B not work) , (the existing answer is not good enough)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, hotkeys

In Visual Studio C++ :-

- <kbd>`F5`</kbd> = *compile as **necessary** + run*
- <kbd>`Ctrl+Shift+B`</kbd> = *build all open (loaded) projects , but not run*
- <kbd>`???`</kbd> = compile as **necessary**  but not run

### Example

If I have projects (real case is more complex):-

- `A` : static library
- `B` : depend on `A` (set as **StartUp** project)
- `C` : depend on `A`

Hotkey will do:-

- <kbd>`F5`</kbd> = will build `A` & `B`, then run `B`
- <kbd>`Ctrl+Shift+B`</kbd> = build all `A` & `B` & `C`, but not run
- <kbd>`???`</kbd> = will build `A` & `B`, but not run

### Question

What is the hotkey/button for : *compile as necessary (`A`&`B` only), but not run* ?
... or how to set <kbd>`Ctrl+Shift+B`</kbd> to do as mentioned?

Sorry, it is probably something very obvious.  I have searched it for a few years.

Comment: On VS2022 by default `Ctrl+B` is bound to the command `Build.BuildSelection` (different from `Ctrl+Shift+B` which binds to `Build.BuildSolution`), and enables to build a single executable+dependencies in a multi-executable solution. I don't have a VS2019 install to test, but looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) it should also works there.

Comment: @Vincent ::  Your answer builds the selected project and all related projects.  It is slightly different from what I want (build the "startup" project and all related ones).  Thus, this answer is correct and roughly complete.  Thanks!   If you post it, I will upvote it.   (I have edited question to VS 2022)

Comment: Use Build > Configuration Manager to override what gets built with Ctrl+Shift+B, so untick the Build checkbox for C.

Comment: @Hans Passant :: Thanks.  It is useful, but not in my case.  I change startup project quite often. The tick/untick is too tedious.

Comment: Hmm, this is not a question about setting the startup project.  Your workflow sounds pretty broken.

Comment: @Hans Passant :: Sorry.  I am inexperience.  Is the switching "startup" project often not the way to go?   I only know that "startup" project means get-`main()`-executed.

Answer (score 1):

From the Build option in the top panel go to Configuration Manager (Build > Configuration Manager), check build checkboxes for project A & B only and uncheck unwanted projects (here it is C for your case). That might help your issue.

Comment: It is too tedious.  I will have to remember to do these thing whenever I change start-up project, or else something ugly may happen.  It would be even worse if I have a lot of C (but I don't).  Thanks, it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Visual Studio 2019/2022 keyboard shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>** is bound to the command `Build.BuildSelection` by default (different from **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>** which binds to `Build.BuildSolution`), and enables building a single executable+dependencies in a multi-executable solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think **Ctrl+f7** is what you are looking for my friend.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#to-compile-multiple-c-project-items

Comment: It compiles only 1 cpp.